# Cellular bases of the symmetric group $KS_n$

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, cellular-automata

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group on the set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $K$ a field of characterize $0$.

The definition of cellular algebra refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_algebra . I have known that the group algebra $KS_n$ is a cellular algebra. But I cannot give cellular bases of $KS_n$. Who can give cellular bases of $KS_n$? Any help is needed.

Comment: Look here (page 8, Example 5): https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/ictp2006/lecturenotes/xi.pdf

Comment: @ darko Thank you very much.

Comment: @ darko  I do not understand a place：for example: Fix $n=2$, $\Lambda={\lambda_1 = (2), \lambda_2= (1,1)}$ and $\lambda_1>\lambda_2$, $|M(\lambda_1)|= |M(\lambda_2)| = 1$, $C^{\lambda_1}_{1,1}=1\in S_2$, $C^{\lambda_2}_{1,1}=(12) \in S_2$. But $(1 + (12) ) C^{\lambda_2}_{1,1} = (12) + 1$, which contradicts the condition (3) in the definition of cellular algebra. I don't know where is wrong?

Comment: @bing, did you forget the condition is taken modulo the ideal spanned by $C_{u,s}^{>\lambda_2}$'s.

Comment: @ Aaron The condition (3)  is taken modulo the ideal spanned by $C_{u,s}^{< \lambda_2}$'s.